# CSS setting to modify an element at scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using an Angular package below;

[NPM angular-mgl-timeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-mgl-timeline)

[StackBlitz angular-mgl-timeline](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgl-timeline)

In my settings, I have `overflow:scrol` in my css so that when I add many entries I can scroll down to see until the last entry.

However, I realized that while scrolling works, the time line (the line in the middle) does not extend to the end. I tried to specify `height: auto`, `height: 100%` and `min-height: 100%`. None of which worked.

Is there any way to extend this line as I scroll down?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Care to share your code? Something similar to the example you linked to would be helpful.

Comment: @JDunken
Thank you for your reply. I updated the post with my code.

Comment: @Koji i replaced the StackBlitz code with yours and it works, please check again, replace the 'mgl-timeline' component with yours.

Comment: @phainix
Appreciate your reply. Would you be able to try adding several entries to the time line? Then I think you will know what I meant here. I also uploaded a photo at the bottom of my post for the ease of understanding. Sorry for my poor explanation..

Comment: @Koji, i replaced your code and took a screenshot, please see [screenshot](https://ibb.co/MfdpFth)

Comment: @phainix
Thank you for trying to reproduce my issue but you need to have at least 7 dots (meaning 7 entries) to see what I am seeing here.

Comment: @Koji the issue is reproducible, please see answer below

Answer (score 1):

The `mgl-timeline` component appends a div to represent the `timeline-line` line (The grey line).
From your code you are defining a maximum height to the `mgl-timeline` component `max-height: 70vh;`. The implication is that the `timeline-line` line will also have a maximum height of 70vh.

If you remove this property then the issue disappears, if it is compulsory that you have the maximum height set, you would have to use a different implementation style wise.

1. Disable the default `timeline-line`
2. Attach a pseudo element to each `mgl-timeline-entry`, this means that each timeline entry will have the grey line attached to it, so the entries array can grow as long as possible.

Please see below:

```
.mgl-timeline-line { // Hide the default timeline
    display: none;
}

.mgl-timeline-entry-card-header:before { // Pseudo element is attached to the card which creates the time-line line for each entry
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    height: 300%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: calc((100% - 10px) / 2);
    left: -10px;
    top: -100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It seems to work except for one case. It only works when the time line has a header on the left side. Please see the uploaded image I attached to the post above. I tried to use different classes than ".mgl-timeline-entry-card-header:before". I cannot really get this to work though..

Comment: Please look at this link for the pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrdno.png